# Easiest programing language for string manipulation

Tags: string, programming-languages, text-processing, string-parsing

I want to code a program that given a paragraph of text (letters and numbers), it formats it in a custom way, totally different from the initial source.

The thing I'm wondering is which programming language to use to make it easier to code.

Right now I know some Lua, VB, C and a little less of Python and Java, but I wouldn't mind using other monogramming languages if its easy enough to code it.

Comment: Related: [best-language-for-string-manipulation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635155/best-language-for-string-manipulation)

Answer (score 2):

If it is okay for you to use a non-mainstream language, have a look at [Unicon](http://unicon.sourceforge.net/book/). It is a successor of SNOBOL, the grandfather of all string processing languages.

If you prefer a mainstream language, I would recommend Python.

Comment: +1 I came here to recommend SNOBOL, intending to be snarky.  Thanks for both saving me the effort and for being helpful to the OP.

Comment: I would say Ruby. Somewhat Perl like capability when it comes to regex. But Python modules will do more than what OP would ever want anyway.